# Can a Java applet use v1.7 or 1.8 as available without warning?

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start, jnlp

A small Java applet [Edited: that might not even be the right word: this is JNLP] in a site I support is currently compiled for Java v1.7. As v1.8 becomes increasingly common, our users are getting warnings like Firefox's "This application would like to use a version of Java (1.7) that is not installed on your system. We recommend running the application with the latest version of Java on your computer." Is there some way we could rebuild our applet to try for the 1.8 Java first and only try for the older 1.7 if 1.8 isn't available, preferably without needing to ask the user in either case? (FWIW, I'm a very experienced developer, but a rather inexperienced Java developer.)

Comment: Does the html have a line like this in the `<applet>` section?
`<param name="java_version" value="1.7*">`

Comment: Hmm, I may have been wrong even to use the word "applet" (that must be more specific than I realized, as I said, rather inexperienced Java developer; this is JNLP). Because there is nothing here like HTML with an "applet" element.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. Does your .jnlp file have a `<resources>` section that specifies a java version like `<j2se version="1.7*">`?  If so, changing the asterisk to a plus might solve your problem so it's "1.7+" instead.

Comment: Actually, it has <j2se version="1.7"/>. That's doubtless the culprit. Not at work right now, but I'll change that to "1.7+" when I am. Thanks! If you write that up as an answer (and on the very likely assumption that it solves the problem) I can credit you for the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The applet can specify the version of java required using a line like this in the `<resources>` section of the code:

`<j2se version="1.7*">`

The version number specified can either end with a number, and asterisk or a plus sign.

- **1.7** would mean the version must be 1.7.
- **1.7*** means anything at or higher than 1.7 but less than 1.8 (like 1.7.1).
- **1.7+** means anything 1.7 or higher (including 1.8).

If your code should run fine on Java 7 or Java 8, then you'd want "**1.7+**" to indicate you're not that picky about it.

Comment: Possibly premature in accepting this (my QC guy could yet tell me it didn't solve things) but it sure looks like the answer I was looking for. Thanks!